# Wikipedia API Wrapper WPTOOLS

Tags: python

Usually, when using wptools, an API wrapper for Python I get a 'mostviewed' dictionary under 'data' when I do something like this:

```
site = wptools.site('en.wikipedia.org')   or 
blah = site.get_info('en.wikipedia.org')  or
fdgfdg= site.top('en.wikipedia.org')
```

The dictionary (under data) returned contains the most viewed pages for, in this case the English version of wikipedia.org
but lately, the dictionary is empty (I changed nothing in the original version and created a new project to test from scratch but nothing). What can I do to regain this functionality cleanly and quickly in Python 3.7?

Comment: I don't know why, especially as a first question, this has been voted down, just seems unfriendly without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to resolve within 24 hours so I assumed A. I had hit some rate limit as caching wasn't happening under development version. or
B. wptools or wikipedia API was undergoing some change. 
...but I can't see any rate limits for this usage and issue ocurring again.
Here is Python code I am using resulting in an empty list returned [ ]

```
    wptools_site_object = wptools.site('en.wikipedia.org')
    wptools_site_object.top('en.wikipedia.org')
    mostviewedtopics = wptools_site_object.data['mostviewed']
```